# Calculating a complex table relationship in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am hoping that this fine group may have some suggestions to help in a difficult issue I've been having.  I'm working on an Access Database for statistical event reporting from a large daily batch cycle which deals with several hundred applications, which in turn submit several hundred thousand events to run daily.  I'm working on being able to statistically gather reporting information based on multiple criteria...

At the moment, the database is fairly simple.  Two tables.

Application Data - a table containing an entry for each individual application and all of its associated data (name, developer, team, business unit, architect, etc). Applications are named with either 2 or 3 character codes, for example Applicaiton X may be referred to as XYZ, application Y may be referred to as YF.

Event Data - Gathered daily, this is a listing of all events that have run. It stores event information such as event name, date, success status, runtime, max completion code, etc.

events are defined within the system with a naming convention.  The events can have names up to 8 characters.  The first character is always 'P' indicating a production events.  The next 2 or 3 characters are the application code, and the remaining characters can be anything the application desires.

What I am trying to do is to match each event entry to its associated application in the application data table (so that I can then report on all event information for a specific application, or even the events for all applications owned by a specific architect, etc)

My problem is, currently the only real way to determine the relationship is to parse the event name and compare. What I am trying to do is take the 2nd, 3rd and 4th characters and compare that to the application data tables application code field.  If it find a match, that is the application, and I can take that record and add the application data ID as a foreign key for a relationship. If there is no match, then use the first 2 characters to match to determine if it is a 2 character application code, and again, fill out a foreign key for the application data in the even data table.

I have tried using a query comparing event name (parsed with mid strings) and a series of IIF statements, but that blew up spectacularly and I simply couldn't make the complex syntax work.  My next thought was to do it in batch with a vba module to parse the event name in each record, and search the application data application code field for a match, then update the foreign key field. But that is, I believe something I could have to do regularly as new daily event data is added.

I'm not even sure if what I am asking is possible, but I would welcome any thoughts on an automated way to populate a foreign key field based on this criteria, or a manual solution I could run daily that would account for the huge volumes of data.

Thank you. 
Gord

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that using a series of SQL statements in VBA may be the way to go.

Firstly, you should be importing the data into a temporary table that matches the structure of you Event table. By doing this, it means that when you are doing the updating, you have less data to work with, so should be quicker doing updates.

I'm assuming that the Application table has an Autonumber Primary Key, and that the Event/Temp tables have a numeric Foreign Key that is to be updated. You can then run some VBA:

```
Sub sEventData()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    db.Execute "UPDATE tblTemp AS T INNER JOIN tblApplication AS A ON A.ApplicationCode=Mid(T.EventName,2,3) " _
        & " SET T.ApplicationID=A.ApplicationID " _
        & " WHERE T.ApplicationID=0;"
    db.Execute "UPDATE tblTemp AS T INNER JOIN tblApplication AS A ON A.ApplicationCode=Mid(T.EventName,2,2) " _
        & " SET T.ApplicationID=A.ApplicationID " _
        & " WHERE T.ApplicationID=0;"
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO tblEvent (EventName,EventDate, ApplicationID) " _
        & " SELECT EventName, EventDate, ApplicationID " _
        & " FROM tblTemp " _
        & " WHERE ApplicationID<>0;"
    db.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblTemp WHERE ApplicationID<>0;"
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sEventData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

This deals with any items that can be matched on 3 characters, then those that haven't been matched but can be matched on 2 characters. It then inserts the matched items into your main Event table, and then deletes any matched items. This will leave you with any unmatched items that you may have to create new records in the Application table for,

Regards,